# copy lastrow of masterfile to multiple created worksheets then perform a Subtotal formula in a column lastrow

Tags: vba, excel, loops, excel-formula

I have a master file which is (JV501) where I filter through column AB (currency) then copy those to createdsheets, my problem  now is the lastrow from master file which I need to include to every created worksheets since it starts in column R and from there under column AD (which is all null) lastrow  is where I shall perform a subtotal of AC2 up to lastrow so the subtotal shall inline with the lastrow copied.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SortCurrency()
    Dim currRng As Range, dataRng As Range, currCell As Range
    Dim LastCol As Long, lastRow As Long, lastrow2 As Long, TheLastRow As Long

    Call DeleteSheets

    With Worksheets("JV501")
        Set currRng = .Range("AB1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp))
        Set dataRng = Intersect(.UsedRange, currRng.EntireRow)

        LastCol = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
        TheLastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        lastRow = Range("AB2").End(xlDown).Row
        Range("AB2:AB" & lastRow).sort key1:=Range("AB2" & lastRow), _
        order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
        Range("AF:XFD").EntireColumn.Delete

        With .UsedRange
            With .Resize(1, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count)
                With .Resize(currRng.Rows.Count)
                    .Value = currRng.Value
                    .RemoveDuplicates Array(1), Header:=xlYes
                    For Each currCell In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                        currRng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=currCell.Value
                        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, currRng) - 1 > 0 Then
                            dataRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=GetOrCreateWorksheet(currCell.Value).Range("A1")
                            Range("J:Q").EntireColumn.Delete
                            Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Delete
                            Columns("A:AE").Select
                            Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit

                        End If
                    Next currCell
                    .ClearContents

                End With
            End With
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    Call checklist
End Sub
Function GetOrCreateWorksheet(shtName As String) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetOrCreateWorksheet = Worksheets(shtName)
    If GetOrCreateWorksheet Is Nothing Then
        Set GetOrCreateWorksheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        GetOrCreateWorksheet.Name = shtName
    End If
End Function
```

this is my code so far. I'm confused if how I shall do this.
Every help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In trying to compute for a a column range i've come up and got it working by adding this in my loop in creating sheets.

```
 'subtotal of debit
                            lastrowSrc = Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            Range("AC" & lastrowSrc & ":AC" & lastrowSrc).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,AC2:AC" & lastrowSrc - 1 & ")"

                            'copy ac to ad
                            Range("AC" & lastrowSrc & ":AC" & lastrowSrc).Cut Destination:=Range("AC" & lastrowSrc).Offset(0, 1)
```

in column AC is where I will compute the subtotal of debit then copy it to another column which is AD which is null I've pasted it by column AC then offset

For copying the columns not included in criteria of extracting I've done it one by one

```
dim internalS as long, 'and so on
 internalR = Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            copyR.Copy Destination:=Range("R" & internalR)

                            internalS = Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            copyS.Copy Destination:=Range("S" & internalS)

                            internalT = Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            copyT.Copy Destination:=Range("T" & internalT)

                            internalU = Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            copyU.Copy Destination:=Range("U" & internalU)

                            internalV = Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            copyV.Copy Destination:=Range("V" & internalV)

                            internalW = Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            copyW.Copy Destination:=Range("W" & internalW)

                            internalX = Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            copyX.Copy Destination:=Range("X" & internalX)

                            internalY = Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            copyY.Copy Destination:=Range("Y" & internalY)

                            internalZ = Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            copyZ.Copy Destination:=Range("Z" & internalZ)

                            internalAE = Range("AE" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            copyAE.Copy Destination:=Range("AE" & internalAE)
```

also inserted this in my loop in creating new worksheets